# struggling to create menu dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble to create menu dynamically. I had a simple menu before and all worked, but had to move to a responsive design. Now I am using menu from here: http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/bootstrap-navbar.html 
When created statically (in html) all is fine.
To create dynamically I use the code:

```
      $('#wsnmotes > ul').append(

    '<li class="subfirst" id="wsnnode"><a val='wsnnode' href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;mote name:X1</a>'+
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'+

            '<li><a id='discover' href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;Discover</a> </li>'+
            '<li><a id='moteconfig' href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Mote Config</a></li>'+
            '<li><a id='sensors' href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>&nbsp;Sensors</a>'+ 
                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'+

                    '<li class="subfirst"><a val='chart' dev='accel' href="#">accel</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='voltage' href="#">voltage</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='temperature' href="#">temperature</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='light' href="#">light</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='io' href="#">i/o</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='pwm' href="#">pwm</a></li>'+

                '</ul>'+
            '</li>'+
            '<li><a id='actuators' href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;Actuators</a>'+  
                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'+

                    '<li class="subfirst"><a val='chart' dev='accel' href="#">accel</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='voltage' href="#">voltage</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='temperature' href="#">temperature</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='light' href="#">light</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='io' href="#">i/o</a></li>'+
                    '<li><a val='chart' dev='pwm' href="#">pwm</a></li>'+

                '</ul>'+ 
              '</li>'+   
            '</ul>'+

            '</li>'

            );
```

... and nothing happens.

Comment: Your quotes don't match. You can see from the syntax highlighting. I would strongly suggest you use a templating framework, such as Mustache, when generating a block of HTML this size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the single quote used which is breaking the javascript code , either use the double quote or use the escape character \ to use the single quote

```
              <a val=\'wsnnode\' href="#">
```

or

```
              <a val="wsnnode" href="#">
```

Comment: thanks for that, however still no solution. Found what is causing the problem, but don't know how to fix. The following simplified example

Answer (score 0):

thanks for that, however still no solution. Found what is causing the problem, but don't know how to fix. The following simplified example appears to work, but with a strange styling : 
However placing the class="dropdown-menu" inside the ul, makes everything disappear. The same code works when static.

```
    // test 05/03/2015
 $('#Action').click(function(){
  //alert("Action");
  $("#wsnmotes > ul").append(
    '<li id="wsnnode"><a val="wsnnode" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>&nbsp;mote name: L1</a>'+
      '<ul id="sub1">'+
        '<li><a id="discover" href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>&nbsp;Discover</a> </li>'+
        '<li><a id="moteconfig" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp;Mote Config</a></li>'+
      '</ul>'+
      '</li>'
  );

  //$("#sub1").addClass("dropdown-menu");
  });                

                                                         however when placing class="dropdown-menu" inside the ul makes everything disappear. Any advice, please?
```

Jan